# Insertar variable en clase en Python respetando su posición

Tags: python, array, lista, clase, insert

Tengo un programa en Python que lee un archivo.txt con el siguiente formato:

```
7 3
31 18
19 36
55 63
21 29
14 58
18 54
22 25
```

El cuál a partir de la segunda línea crea una lista bidimensional en donde los números de la izquierda son representados como "x" y de la derecha como "y".

Seguido de esto, tengo una variable que adquiere un par de coordenadas de manera aleatoria, y después se saca la distancia de esas coordenadas con todas las demás dentro de la lista original. Esto mismo es para calcular las distancias entre las coordenadas escogidas aleatoriamente con las demás, por lo cuál hice la siguiente fórmula:

```
for i in range(0, len(main_array)-1):
   distance = math.sqrt((initpoint.x - main_array[i].x) ** 2 + (initpoint.y - main_array[i].y) ** 2)
   distance = round(distance)
   main_array.append(distance)
```

Al momento de querer adjuntarlo con el resto de la clase no me respeta la posición en la que debería de estar, es decir, al sacar la primera distancia quisiera que estuviera con los valores 31, 18, 1. Por ejemplo:

```
[31 : 18 : 1 : 11, 19 : 36 : 2 : 11, 55 : 63 : 3 : 50, 21 : 29 : 4 : 4, 14 : 58 : 5 : 34, 18 : 54 : 6 : 29, 22 : 25 : 7]
```

En lugar de eso, me genera las distancias al final:

```
[31 : 18 : 1, 19 : 36 : 2, 55 : 63 : 3, 21 : 29 : 4, 14 : 58 : 5, 18 : 54 : 6, 22 : 25 : 7, 11, 11, 50, 4, 34, 29]
```

De igual manera, me percaté que solo me genera las distancias de 6 coordenadas en lugar de 7, como debería de ser. Apreciaría una solución o método porque por el momento no se me ocurre alguna. Debo de hacer énfasis en que es sumamente importante que se respeten las posiciones con cada una ya que más adelante debo de ordenar los valores de mayor a menor según sus distancias. Gracias de antemano, adjunto el código

```
import numpy as np
import math
import random
from operator import attrgetter

fileName = open('outputfile1.txt','r')

main_array = []

class Array:
   def __init__(self, x, y, pos):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.pos = pos

   def __repr__(self):
       return '{} : {} : {}'.format(self.x, self.y, self.pos)

def extract_values(line):
   a, b = line.split()
   return int(a), int(b)

pos = 0
with open('outputfile1.txt','r') as file:
   main_array = []

   n, p = extract_values(file.readline())
   for line in file.readlines():
       x, y = extract_values(line)
       pos = pos + 1
       main_array.append(Array(x, y, pos))

initpoint = random.choice(list(main_array))


for i in range(0, len(main_array)-1):
   distance = math.sqrt((initpoint.x - main_array[i].x) ** 2 + (initpoint.y - main_array[i].y) ** 2)
   distance = round(distance)
   main_array.append(distance)

print(main_array)
```

Nota: La variable "pos" es sobre la posición de las coordenadas, lo cuál usaré a futuro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que aparezca el valor al hacer el `print()` debes agregarlo en la función `__repr__` y por tanto agregarlo como propiedad a tu clase `Array`.

Luego al iterar puedes aprovecharte de la [mutabilidad en Python](https://ellibrodepython.com/mutabilidad-python) para dentro del ciclo cambiar directamente el valor que está en el arreglo.

```py
import numpy as np
import math
import random
from operator import attrgetter

main_array = []

class Array:
   def __init__(self, x, y, pos):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.pos = pos
       # Se agrega la propiedad dist
       self.dist = '-'

   def __repr__(self):
       # se agrega que se imprima la distancia cuando se imprima el objeto
       return '{} : {} : {} : {}'.format(self.x, self.y, self.pos, self.dist)

def extract_values(line):
   a, b = line.split()
   return int(a), int(b)

pos = 0
with open('./outputfile1.txt','r') as file:
   main_array = []
   n, p = extract_values(file.readline())
   for line in file.readlines():
       x, y = extract_values(line)
       pos = pos + 1
       main_array.append(Array(x, y, pos))

initpoint = random.choice(list(main_array))

# se itera sobre el array de objetos
for coord in main_array:
    # se calcula la distancia entre el punto inicial y el punto actual
    distance = math.sqrt((initpoint.x - coord.x) ** 2 + (initpoint.y - coord.y) ** 2)
    distance = round(distance)
    # se setea la distancia en el objeto actual
    coord.dist = distance

print(main_array)
```